# two child process communicating through named pipe

Tags: c

I have main program which creates two children and one named pipe(FIFO). Each children executes a program called “sendSignal" via execv(). One of the argument of the “sendSignal” is the FIFO in the main program.

The children are going to send signal to each other. It decided with an argument in the main (in variable firstShooter)program which signal shoot first.

I want to know how these two children can send each other their pid through this named pipe.

Following is the main program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

/* this program should be provided with 2 arguments */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   char str1[15];
   char str2[15];
   char fileDescriptor[15];
   char *my_args[4];
   char *myfifo = "myfifo";

  int fd, pipeCheck;
  pid_t pid1, pid2, wid;


  /* If the user does not provide the argument to determin which child is firing first */
  if(argc != 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"%s: 2 arguments needed, got %d\n",argv[0],argc-1);
    exit(1);
  }

  /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
  pipeCheck = mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

   /* check if the named pipe was created properly if not output an error */
   if(pipeCheck == -1)
   {
     fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error creating named pipe: %s\n",argv[0], strerror(errno));
      exit(1);    
   }


   pid1 = fork();

   if (pid1 < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, ": fork failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
    }

    if(pid1 == 0)
    {


      my_args[0] = "sendSignal";
      my_args[1] = argv[1];
      my_args[2] = myfifo; //  the named pipe as arguemnt
      my_args[3] = NULL;
      execv("sendSignal",my_args);
      fprintf(stderr,"sendSignal cannot be executed by first child...");
      exit(-1);
    }


     pid2 = fork();

    if(pid2 < 0)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, ": fork failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
       exit(1);
    }

    if(pid2 == 0)
    {

      my_args[0] = "sendSignal";
      my_args[1] = argv[1];
      my_args[2] = myfifo;  // named pipe as arguemnt
      my_args[3] = NULL; 
     // printf("this is converted = %s\n",my_args[1]);
      execv("sendSignal",my_args);
      fprintf(stderr,"sendSignal cannot be executed by second child...");
      exit(-1);
    }

close(fd);
unlink(myfifo);


wid = wait(NULL);


return 0;

}
```

here is the sendSignal:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>


void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if(signo == SIGUSR1)
        printf("signal received\n");

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

     char abspath[256] = "";
     getcwd(abspath, 256);
     strrchr(abspath, '/');

     if(signal(SIGUSR1,sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\n Cannot catch the signal\n");

     char *myfifo = "myfifo";

     int firstShooter = atoi(argv[1]);  //define the first process to send the signal 

     int fd;
     char str1[15];
     char str2[15];
     char pid1[15];
     char pid2[15];

     fd = open(argv[2],O_RDWR);


     if(firstShooter == 1)
     {
        sprintf(pid1,"%d",getpid());
        write(fd,pid1,sizeof(pid1));
     }

     if(firstShooter == 2)
     {
        sprintf(pid2,"%d",getpid());
        write(fd,pid2,sizeof(pid2));
     }


     read(fd,str1,sizeof(str2));
     read(fd,str2,sizeof(str2));

    close(fd);

    printf("str1 = %s\n",str1);
    printf("str2 = %s\n",str2);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your children processes got the same arguments:

```
my_args[0] = "sendSignal";
my_args[1] = argv[1];
my_args[2] = myfifo; //  the named pipe as argument
my_args[3] = NULL;
```

`firstShooter` parameter doesn't make sense as process cannot identify itself as first or second.

I suggest to add one more parameter - process index. `sendSignal` function logic can be modified this way:

```
char pid1[15];
char pid2[15];
int processIndex = atoi(argv[3]);

fd = open(argv[2],O_RDWR);

if (processIndex == firstShooter)
{
  // Send firstShooter PID
  sprintf(pid1,"%d",getpid());
  write(fd,pid1,sizeof(pid1));

  // Got the other PID
  read(fd,pid2,sizeof(pid2));
}
else
{
  // Got the firstShooter PID
  read(fd,pid1,sizeof(pid1));

  // Send the other PID
  sprintf(pid2,"%d",getpid());
  write(fd, pid2, sizeof(pid2));
}

close(fd);

printf("pid1 = %s\n",pid1);
printf("pid2 = %s\n",pid2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the way you have implemented.
1.Calling two fork() in the main program will be creating more than two child processes.(3 child processes). So give a condition to check that you are calling the next fork in the context of the parent itself.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

/* this program should be provided with 2 arguments */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int * status;
    char str1[15];
    char str2[15];
    char fileDescriptor[15];
    char *my_args[4];
    char *myfifo = "myfifo";

    int fd, pipeCheck;
    pid_t pid1, pid2, wid;


    /* If the user does not provide the argument to determin which child is firing first */
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s: 2 arguments needed, got %d\n",argv[0],argc-1);
        exit(1);
    }

     /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    pipeCheck = mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    /* check if the named pipe was created properly if not output an error */
    if(pipeCheck == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error creating named pipe: %s\n",argv[0], strerror(errno));
        exit(1);    
    }


   pid1 = fork();

   if (pid1 < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, ": fork failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
    }

    if(pid1 == 0)//child
    {
//  printf("pid1=0\n");
        printf("i am child 1 %d\n",getpid());
        my_args[0] = "sendSignal";
        my_args[1]=malloc(6);
        sprintf(my_args[1] , "%d", getpid());
        //my_args[1]="1";
        printf("p%s\n",my_args[1]);
        my_args[2] = myfifo; //  the named pipe as arguemnt
        my_args[3] ="1";
        execv("sendSignal",my_args);
        fprintf(stderr,"sendSignal cannot be executed by first child...");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if(pid1>0)// parent
    {
        //  printf("pid1 %d",pid1);
        waitpid(pid1,&status,WIFEXITED(status));
        pid2 = fork();
        //  printf("p:%d",pid2);
    if(pid2 < 0)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, ": fork failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
       exit(1);
    }
    if(pid2 == 0)
    {
        printf("i am child 2 %d\n",getpid());
        my_args[0] = "sendSignal";
        my_args[1]=malloc(6);
        sprintf(my_args[1] , "%d", getpid());
        my_args[2] = myfifo;  // named pipe as arguemnt
        my_args[3] = "2"; 
        // printf("this is converted = %s\n",my_args[1]);
        execv("sendSignal",my_args);
        fprintf(stderr,"sendSignal cannot be executed by second child...");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("done\n");
    }

close(fd);
wait(NULL);
fd=open("fifo1", O_RDONLY);
char * space=(char *)malloc(6);
read(fd,space,6);
printf("from fifo1 %s",space);

fd=open("fifo2", O_RDONLY);
//char * space=(char *)malloc(6);
read(fd,space,6);
printf("from fifo2 %s",space);
//unlink(myfifo);


wid = wait(NULL);
unlink(myfifo);

return 0;

}
```

2. The two child process are accessing the same pipe. Pipe is for one way communication with an end for reading and another for writing. So create two pipes each for a process. I would suggest better not to go for pipes.

Comment: First suggestion is not required as in child process (`if(pid1 == 0)`) `exit(-1);` will be executed. 2) pipes could be used for reading/writing by any process, the only problem is to correctly synchronize access. Read more about it in [mkfifo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) documentation.